# Add source app to the header of FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sharing

I'm trying to add name of the app to header of `FBSDKShareDialog` as it shown on first screenshot but can't find property that responsible for it. I'm sharing `FBSDKSharePhotoContent`, it's shown on second screenshot. Do anyone know how to implement this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836080/where-to-set-the-shared-via-text-for-a-facebook-app

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a property that you can set in `FBSDKShareDialog`. The app name is taken from your app settings page. You will need to set up your [app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) correctly for this. You can find additional information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#settings).